# Prevent jumping of UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and each cell inside it represents a message in a chat-like view. I set the top content offset everytime a new cell is added so that the cells "stick" to the bottom of the UICollectionView and new ones push the cells up the screen like this:

```
------------
|-----
|  // This space represents a content offset from the top
|-----
A
B
C
D // Each of these is a UICollectionViewCell
------------
```

This works fine. However, after 8 seconds I remove the `UICollectionViewCell` at the top of the `UICollectionView`. This makes the remaining cells move up to fill its place and then I set the content offset to accommodate for the lost cell and they all move back down to act as if they're stuck to the bottom of the `UICollectionView`. How can I make it so that the removal of the top `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't make the rest of the cells jump up and down like this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `contentOffset` property to manipulate the top offset. In `UICollectionView` all the properties like `contentOffset`, `contentSize`, etc. are managed by `UICollectionViewLayout`, which can be custom to match your specific needs. As for me, there are two options (by priority):

**1)** Look for a custom layout (or implement one by yourself) which would let you achieve the desired chat-like behavior

**2)** Insert a dummy empty cell at the top of your collectionView and every time you delete/add any new cells, manage the dummy one's height to achieve the goal by invalidating its layout or just calling `collectionView.reloadItems([IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the need for contentOffset and using the following steps:

1. Perform 180 degree rotation of `UICollectionView`: `collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: 0)`
2. Apply the transform on the contentView of each cell in the collectionView: `cell.contentView.transform = collectionView.transform`
3. Reverse data array used in collectionView: `myData.reversed()`